# using strcmp between string array and 2d array string

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c-strings, strcmp, function-definition

I need to search a word in 2d array an array that I enter but when Im using strcmp function, I have an error "No Matching function for call to 'strcmp'

```
bool checkIfSameMedicine (char str1[], char str2[][MAXSIZE])
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(str2, str1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` returns 0 if both strings matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write at least

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(str2[i], str1) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Though the code  looks not good due to using the magic number `3`.

The function should be declared and defined like

```
bool checkIfSameMedicine( const char str2[][MAXSIZE]), size_t n, const char str1[] )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i != n && strcmp( str2[i], str1 ) != 0 ) ++i;

    return n != 0 && i != n;
}
```

Comment: i changed the 1st code and added an define instead of 3, 
i couldnt understand the 2nd func you wrote since im pretty new to c++ i hope you may explain please :)

Comment: @ShakedBarel In the second function each element of the two-dimensional array str2 is compared with the string stored in the array str1. If such element is not found then i will be equal to n.  If such element is found then i != n.